# Is it a good practice to *compile* Python3 for Lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In Bash I can do:

`python3 -OO -m py_compile myscript.py`

And build deployment zip with `__pycache__` inside, for multiple scripts I can run:

`python3 -OO -m compileall .`

Executing this in the same [underlying AMI image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html).

Is it wise for AWS Lambda performance improvement?

Comment: Does the python interpreter not do this naturally the first time you run the script?

Comment: @roganjosh Many Lambda calls will run with a fresh deployment package - without `__pycache__`. I think AWS Lambda does not cache it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, but it's probably a bit of a premature optimisation.

Lambda has two parts to it's performance:

1. Transfer, build and init the container for each concurrent execution
2. Run the code for each execution

`.pyc` files offer you some optimisation of 1, or the "cold start" time. This is because you can ship *only* the `pyc` files, and they tend to be smaller (reducing transfer time), and because you have already compiled to byte code, which takes away a step of the build process (note that python is still compiled further, but it's an optimisation none-the-less).

Frankly, I'd be surprised if this made a difference enough to justify the added complexity at deployment and the resulting opaqueness of the code in the lambda console. And so I would challenge you to profile using something like X-Ray before you commit to this optimisation over anything in your actual code.

(n.b. MapBox have a good article about reducing size and discussing the effect of `.pyc` deployments: https://blog.mapbox.com/aws-lambda-python-magic-e0f6a407ffc6)

Comment: Is this true? You can ship _only_ the .pyc files and set the handler using the same method of `file.handler_function` and it will still work if "file" is `file.pyc` and not `file.py`?

Comment: Yup- because AWS (and python, come to that) isn't finding if by [filename].handler_function, it's importing a module and running that function; and modules can be pyc.